# how to mount laravel filament project with vite functions on apache 2.4 server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

URLs generated by @vite don't work. Is it necessary to raise any service? How to set up the service only with PHP and Laravel in APACHE?

I have manually typed the URLs but that is not the solution.

When trying to deploy a Laravel Filament project with Vite functions on an Apache 2.4 server, there are issues with the URLs generated by Vite. The central problem is how to configure Vite to automatically generate URLs, but with a configured URL.

Vite is installed correctly but I don't know how to configure it without going into the suppliers folder.

I know it shouldn't be very difficult but I already searched and everything tells me to modify that folder